# Rewriting Cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm building a javascript shopping cart where the user can add a product to the cart using a button and be able to go to the cart overview section to change the quantity of the product by inserting a number into the input field and pressing update cart. If the quantity of the product is zero it won't appear in the cart. My problem is that I'm trying to get the value from the corresponding input field inside the updateCart function and rewrite the cookie with that value and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. How would I go about this?

```js
function retrieveCookie(cName) {
 if(document.cookie){
  var cookieArray = document.cookie.split("; ");
  for(var i = 0; i < cookieArray.length; i++) {
   if(cookieArray[i].split("=")[0] == cName) {
    return unescape(cookieArray[i].split("=")[1]);
   }
  }
 }
}

function writeCookie(cName, cValue, expDate, cPath, cDomain, cSecure) {
  if (cName && cValue != "") {
     var cString = cName + "=" + escape(cValue);
     if (expDate) 
        cString += ";expires=" + expDate.toGMTString();

     if (cPath) cString += ";path=" + cPath;
     if (cDomain) cString += ";domain=" + cDomain;
     if (cSecure) cString += ";secure";


     document.cookie = cString;
  }
}

var productPics = new Array();
var pictureDesc = new Array();
var productPrice = new Array();
var productShortName = new Array();

productPics[0] = "AllTheKids.jpg";
productPics[1] = "susie.jpg";
productPics[2] = "princess.jpg";
productPics[3] = "wicketAndCarlos.jpg";
productPics[4] = "wicketAndGeorge.jpg";

productShortName[0] = "atk";
productShortName[1] = "s";
productShortName[2] = "p";
productShortName[3] = "wac";
productShortName[4] = "wag";

productPrice[0] = "5.00";
productPrice[1] = "5.00";
productPrice[2] = "5.00";
productPrice[3] = "5.00";
productPrice[4] = "5.00";

pictureDesc[0] = "product1";
pictureDesc[1] = "product2";
pictureDesc[2] = "product3";
pictureDesc[3] = "product4";
pictureDesc[4] = "product5";

alert(document.cookie);

function writeTable() {

  var table = "<table border='1'><thead><tr><td>Product</td><td>Description</td><td>Price</td><td>Purchase</td></tr></thead>";

  for (var i = 0; i < productPics.length; i++) {
    table += "<tr><td><a href='" + productPics[i].replace(/.jpg/, '.html') + "'><img src='" + productPics[i] + "' height='100px'></a></td>"
    table += "<td>" + pictureDesc[i] + "</td>"
    table += "<td>$" + productPrice[i] + "</td>"
    var results = (retrieveCookie(productPics[i].replace(/.jpg/, ''))) ? retrieveCookie(productPics[i].replace(/.jpg/, '')) : 0;
    table += "<td><input type='button' onclick='addToCart(" + i + ")'  value='Add To Cart'></td></tr>";
  }
  table += "</table>";
  document.write(table);
}

function addToCart(index) {
  var cookieName = productShortName[index] + '~' + productPrice[index];
  if (retrieveCookie(cookieName)) {

    writeCookie(cookieName, parseInt(retrieveCookie(cookieName)) + 1);
  } else {
    writeCookie(cookieName, "1");
  }
}

function viewCart() {

  var table = "<table border='1'><thead><tr><td>Product</td><td>Description</td><td>Price</td><td>Quantity</td></tr></thead>";


  for (var i = 0; i < productPics.length; i++) {
    var cookieName = productShortName[i] + '~' + productPrice[i];
    if (retrieveCookie(cookieName)) {
      table += "<tr><td><a href='" + productPics[i].replace(/.jpg/, '.html') + "'><img src='" + productPics[i] + "' height='100px'></a></td>"
      table += "<td>" + pictureDesc[i] + "</td>"
      table += "<td>$" + productPrice[i] + "</td>"
      var cartValue = (retrieveCookie(cookieName)) ? retrieveCookie(cookieName) : 0;
      table += "<td><input class='cartInputs' type='text' id='" + cookieName + "' value='" + cartValue + "'></td></tr>";
    }
  }
  var total = 'total';
  table += "<td colspan='2'><input type='button' onclick='updateCart()' value='Update Cart'>"
  table += "</td><td>Total:</td><td>" + total + "</td>"
  table += "</table></br>";
  document.write(table);
}

function updateCart() {
  var inputValues = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  var cookieName = productShortName[index] + '~' + productPrice[index];

  if (inputValues.id = cookieName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < inputValues.length; i++) {
      writeCookie(cookieName, document.getElementById(cookieName).value);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Shopping Cart</title>
   
   <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
   <script src = "cookies.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="twoColLiqLtHdr">

<div id="container"> 
 
</div>
<div id="mainContent">
    <h2>Add to Cart</h2>
    <script>
  writeTable();
 
 </script></br>
 <h2>Cart Overview</h2>
 <script>
  viewCart();
 
 </script></br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/tree/v2.1.1#readme
Just include it to you website:

```
<script src="/path/to/js.cookie.js"></script>
```

---

Basic Usage

Create a cookie, valid across the entire site:

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value');
```

Create a cookie that expires 7 days from now, valid across the entire site:

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value', { expires: 7 });
```

Create an expiring cookie, valid to the path of the current page:

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value', { expires: 7, path: '' });
```

Read cookie:

```
Cookies.get('name'); // => 'value'
Cookies.get('nothing'); // => undefined
```

Read all visible cookies:

```
Cookies.get(); // => { name: 'value' }
```

Delete cookie:

```
Cookies.remove('name');
```

Delete a cookie valid to the path of the current page:

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value', { path: '' });
Cookies.remove('name'); // fail!
Cookies.remove('name', { path: '' }); // removed!
```